# Bridged network

Tags: windows, ubuntu-gnome, network-bridge, virtualhost, guest-os

I've been having a hard time connecting my Ubuntu server to the WiFi.
Here's the situation. I have a windows 10 as host and the Ubuntu as guest in virtaualbox and I istablished a connection between the two via bridged network. The ping goes both ways 
The problem is when the host is connected via WiFi the guest is not. But when I use Ethernet cable the guest connect to the internet as well.

Comment: You have to change the bridged adapter in the VM's settings whenever you change from Ethernet to WiFi. "Bridge" here means a connection between the Virtuabox's virtual network adapter and one physical network adapter from the host.

Comment: Well Everytime I unplug the Ethernet cable I uncheck the Ethernet adapter in the bridge setting if that what you mean.

Comment: Uncheck? Do you mean change it to the WiFi?

Comment: Yeah I created the bridge adapter between VirtualBox Host-Only and the Ethernet. When I unplug the cable I go to the bridge adapter properties and add the wifi adapter to bridge and remove the Ethernet

Comment: It should work just like that.

Comment: I know, that's why I have no idea why is not working